# How to use value outside http.then in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My code of controller is : -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    $scope.year = "1350";
    $scope.ord1 = "";
    $scope.s1t1 = function() {
        $http({
            url: 's1t1.json',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.set = response.data;
            //console.log($scope.set);
            $scope.obj = $scope.set.find(o => o.year === $scope.year);
            $scope.ord1 = $scope.obj.ordinal;
        });
    }
    alert($scope.ord1);
});
```

I get a value like 44144 in `$scope.ord1`. and I need to use it in my controller outside  `s1t1` function. I represent It with a alert. I am also try it with `$rootScope` but result is same.

Comment: `$http` is aync

Comment: Your alert is executed even if your http is not yet finish and your function s1t1 is not even called.

Comment: Yes It provide value before s1t1 function excute. and I want to know how I get value of ord1 after execution of s1t1 function ?

Answer (score 1):

Things are not executed sequentially (synchronously) in your code. `$http` is asynchronous, which means that the `function` is called, a request is sent but your code will not wait for a response and just after the `function` call you do not have a value *yet*. You will need to put your code which depends on the response inside the callback in the `then`.

Comment: Actually I have 4 then function. and they provide result ord1, ord2, ord3 and ord4  and its result is added. so I cant place inside then. So is there any method which executed it sequentially ?

Comment: @R.Kumar in that case you can put your second call inside the callback of the first. Put the third call inside the callback of the second and put the fourth callback inside the callback of the third. The main thing is that you need not to expect your code to run sequentially on async calls and handle the sequence by putting the right code into the right callback.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` inside the then function, it will take a small amount of time but you will get a value. Call a function where you want to use the value.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
 $scope.year = "1350";
 $scope.ord1 = "";
 $scope.s1t1 = function() {
    $http({
        url: 's1t1.json',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.set = response.data;
        //console.log($scope.set);
        $scope.obj = $scope.set.find(o => o.year === $scope.year);
        $scope.ord1 = $scope.obj.ordinal;
        alert($scope.ord1);

       // Call a function where you want to use the value
       myFunctionTousevalue();
    });
 }
  var myFunctionTousevalue = function () {
    alert('Using Value: '+$scope.ord1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shubhranshu ..but it not about alert. in that place alert give value. but I need the value of $scope.ord1 outside s1t1 function (outside then function).

Comment: I know, you are trying to get the thing which does not exist now, but will exist after few time. So just make sure you apply the value when it exists not before that.. And if you want the complete help, then please let me know your full requirement

Comment: It has 4 stages like s1t1  and after every stage it returns a value ord1 , ord2 and ord3 then I need sum of ord.  ord = ord1 + ord 2 + ord3

Comment: ok then calculate the sum inside then function and store it in $scope.sumOfOrd object defined outside the $scope.s1t1 function.

Comment: I really appreciate you .. Can you tell me how I place second stage with it. I provide you fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/riseesharma/8jdz45ug/

Answer (score 0):

**Use timeout function**

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp');
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($timeout) {
         $scope.year = "1350";
         $scope.ord1 = "";
         $scope.s1t1 = function() {
            $http({
                url: 's1t1.json',
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.set = response.data;
                //console.log($scope.set);
                $scope.obj = $scope.set.find(o => o.year === $scope.year);
                $scope.ord1 = $scope.obj.ordinal;

               // Call a function in timeout
               $timeout(funuction(){
                    myFunctionTousevalue();        
           },100)

            });
         }
          var myFunctionTousevalue = function () {
            alert('Using Value: '+$scope.ord1);
          }
        });
```